# Optimal reward reinvesting interval with non-zero transaction fee

Tags: sequences-and-series, finance, arithmetic-progressions

#### Description of the system

I have a system where every interval of time *(lets assume every day)* a reward (**n**) is paid out.The amount **n** paid out every day/interval is constant. (i.e n=20$)

I have the option of claiming the reward, which has a **fee** for every withdrawal. (i.e fee=0.40$)

Once claimed the amount **n** can be reinvested and gain a yield **y** per interval. (i.e y=0.2/365)

#### Problem

Obviously claiming the reward too often will diminish the total yield. But also never claiming the reward will result in missed opportunity since reinvesting would give a yield **1+y**. I am looking for the optimal number of intervals between each rewards claim and reinvestment.

#### Possible solution

I wrote a piece of code in python that supposed to solve this problem, but when trying to come up with a mathematical formula to validate the code I was stuck. In short, the function runs a simlation for **d** days, does the claim+reinvest procedure every **restake_interval** days using a modulo operator, and returns the amount accumulated at the end of **d** days.

```
def restaking(restake_interval, n, y, fee, d):
    # restake_interval: interval between each reinvstment
    # n reward amount on each interval
    # y interval yeild %
    # d days/intervals to run the simulation for
    available = 0  # amount available for withdrawal in the system
    amount_staked = 0 # amount already invested that's gaining yield
    for i in range(d):
        available += n
        if (i+1)%restake_interval == 0:
            # claim and reinvest
            amount_staked += available-fee
            available = 0
        amount_staked *= 1+y
    return amount_staked+available
```

By running this function in a loop like this I was able to find the optimal restaking interval. But I am unsure of the result.

```
# find best restake day interval
n=20
interval = 1
prev_result = -1
while True:
    result = restaking(interval, n, 0.2/365, 0.4, 365)
    if result < prev_result:
        break
    interval += 1
    prev_result = result
    
print("\nSOLUTON: restake every {} days: {:.2f}$ gain at {}days".format(interval-1, prev_result, 365))
```

You can run this code online at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php

### Question

What is the mathematical formula/model for solving this problem?
Is the logic behind the code correct?

Comment: What are you trying to maximize? What happens to a reward if you don't claim it? Once a reward has been claimed does it keep accruing the yield forever?

Comment: If you don't claim the reward it just keeps acumulating in the system. Once the reward has been claimed/reinvested it theoretically can keep accuring interest forever, but ofcourse I limited the number of total days with **d**.

What I am trying to maximie is the total yield after **d** days. There must be a formula that gives me the optimal interval between claiming the rewards.

Comment: I played around today with the function and found that it actually converges. Great news. And I also found that since the function is discrete and not continuous, I shouldn't stop looking for the best option when the sequence stop increasing (if result < prev_result:). But I now explore a range and find the maximum in there.

I will post a comment with the new code and an example tomorrow.